# Change input values inside responsive datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a datable with responsive active.

Inside a column i've a input field PRICE. When i change it, it update automatically 1 or more input fields inside others column.

Now if i've a large screen and responsive is not active. All works ok.
But if i've a small screen and responsive active itself, i've problem: input field OUTSIDE the screen are not update.

See the fiddle example trying change PRICE input: http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/5349/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );

    $(".price").on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");

    var total = $(this).val() * ( 1 + tr.find(".vat").val() / 100 );

    tr.find(".txt_no_responsive_column").val(total);

    tr.find(".txt_responsive_column").val(total);

    });

} );
```

I think i've to modify this logic: `var tr = $(this).closest("tr");` .Now i've disabled responsive in all my tables and activated scrollX to get it working. But i'd like to activate responsive in all my tables without pain and without doing deep update to javascript! Any solution valid for responsive triggered and responsive not triggered using unique code?

[image]

UPDATE: I tried solution provided by @Yash Shukla: jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/5361  but i get problem if I resize windows. Value inside new TR back to original value. See pic [image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked you jsfiddle in both cases if responsive is true or false the value in txt_responsive_column input is getting updated.

What is your main issue? If responsive is false then there is no x scroll bar and you are not able to see the input is this the issue?

Edited :

When you click on + sign it creates a new row with child class, so I have updated the jsfiddle with updated code. You just need to pick that new row also and update input values accordingly.

```
//code here
http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/5361/
```

Comment: Hi, option responsive it must be set always to TRUE. The problem occurs when you resize the screen to small, so the columns from the right start to disappear and are moved to the accordion created by the plugin. Added screenshot

Comment: I have updated code in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/5358/, When the accordion is open and then you update textbox value it is getting updated correctly. But if the accordion is closed first time and then you update it does not work you have to look at plus sign code what it is doing

Comment: Hi, thanks for solution. It work well but a new problem occurs: if I then resize the windows (in this case if ' enlarge jsfiddle space where executed code is show), inputs field inside new TR added by plugin return to original value. In this case = empty. I think should be a problem of the plugin? I UPLOAD SCREENSHOT :(

Comment: I found 2 other problems: 1. TOTAL (VAT INCLUDED) is update only when accordion is opened. 2. If I have more rows, TOTAL (VAT INCLUDED) is update in all rows with tha same value.. instead only the row affected by update field. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/5365/

Comment: These problems can be easily resolved using basic js code, I have helped you to resolve the original issue you can try build your own logic based on mine